# Find the determinant of a matrix given the determinant of all $p\times p$ sub-matrices?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices

Is it possible to find the determinant of an $n\times n$- matrix, only given the determinant of all $p\times p$ sub-matrices in it? Here $p\leq n$ is fixed. This is obviously true if $p=1,n$. But what happens in other cases?

Comment: Do you mean contiguous submatrices or arbitrary? At any rate, it seems that if it's true for $n-1$ then there's an inductive argument that shows it is true for all $p$: use the information of $p\times p$ determinants to find all $(p+1)\times (p+1)$ determinants.

Comment: It's arbitrary sub-matrices. But you are right, if $(n-1)$ works then this should be obvious. I'm not sure of the $(n-1)$ case unless it is diagonalizable. So let me edit it out of the question.

Comment: Over $\mathbb C$, if $p$ is not a divisor of $n$ it is impossible, because you can multiply each entry by a $p$th root of unity without affecting the $p \times p$ determinants. This should be the only obstruction - it should be possible to reconstruct the $p/\gcd(n,p)$th power of the determinant using representation theory. For $p=n-1$, this is easy - just take the determinant of the adjugate matrix.

Comment: Likewise, even over $\bf Q$ or $\bf Z$ there will be a sign ambiguity if
$p$ is even and $n$ is odd.

Comment: . . . while if $p|n$ it must be a signed sum of products of $n/p$ determinants 
of rows $(k-1)p+1,\ldots,kp$ and columns $P_k$ ($1 \leq k \leq n/p$)
where $P_1,\ldots,P_{n/p}$ is a partition of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$
(and the sign can be fixed by testing on a permutation matrix).

Comment: @WillSawin, does your [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416659/find-the-determinant-of-a-matrix-given-the-determinant-of-all-p-times-p-sub-ma#comment1069136_416659) say that the answer is no unless $p \mid n$, but also that the answer is yes for $p = n - 1$?  I think that I must be misunderstanding.

Comment: @LSpice I'm saying it's easy to obtain a power of the determinant in the $p=n-1$ case, not the determinant itself.

Comment: Besides the answer that I give below, I strongly suspect that there are syzygies (the $p\times p$ minors are not algebraically idenpendent).

Comment: @DenisSerre: shouldn't the relations among minors (essentially) be Plücker relations?

Comment: @SamHopkins: I guess you're right.

Comment: With a little more detail: the Plücker relations are relations among maximal minors of a non-square matrix; whereas here we consider all minors of a square matrix. But there is a way of associating to any $n\times n$ matrix $B$ an $n \times 2n$ matrix $A$ such that the maximal minors of $A$ correspond to all the minors of $B$: see Lemma 3.9 of https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609764.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416659/find-the-determinant-of-a-matrix-given-the-determinant-of-all-p-times-p-sub-ma#comment1069136_416659) by Will Sawin, a necessary condition is that $p$ divides $n$. Thus let us assume that $n=pk$. Denoting $e_1,\dotsc,e_n$ the canonical basis, the knowledge of the $p\times p$ minors is the knowledge of the $p$-vectors $$(Ae_{i_1})\wedge\cdots\wedge(Ae_{i_p})\in\Lambda^p(K^n),$$
where $K$ is the field of scalars (e.g. $\mathbb C$).

Splitting
$$(Ae_1)\wedge\cdots\wedge (Ae_n) = [(Ae_1)\wedge\cdots\wedge (Ae_p)]\wedge\cdots\wedge[(Ae_{n-p+1})\wedge\cdots\wedge (Ae_n)],
$$
we see that $(Ae_1)\wedge\cdots\wedge (Ae_n)$ is a polynomial function in the $p\times p$ minors. Since $(Ae_1)\wedge\dotsb\wedge (Ae_n)=(\det A)e_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge e_n$, we deduce the value of $\det A$.

Let me describe how it works when $n=4$ and $p=2$. The minors are denoted
$$A\binom{i\alpha}{j\beta}=a_{i\alpha}a_{j\beta}-a_{i\beta}a_{j\alpha}.$$
Then
$$(Ae_\alpha)\wedge(Ae_\beta)=\sum_{i<j}A\binom{i\alpha}{j\beta}e_i\wedge e_j.$$
We thus obtain
$$\det A=\sum_{\substack{\rho\in{\frak S}_4 \\ \rho(1)<\rho(2),\rho(3)<\rho(4)}}A\binom{\rho(1)1}{\rho(2)2}A\binom{\rho(3)3}{\rho(4)4}.$$

Comment: This can also be proved by induction using generalized Laplace expansion.

Comment: TeX note: In case it is of interest, you might find that $\displaystyle\sum_{\rho \in \mathfrak S_4; \rho(1) < \rho(2), \rho(3) < \rho(4)}$ looks better as $\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{\rho \in \mathfrak S_4 \\ \rho(1) < \rho(2), \rho(3) < \rho(4)}}$ `\sum_{\substack{\rho \in \mathfrak S_4 \\ \rho(1) < \rho(2), \rho(3) < \rho(4)}}` (or even an index of summation on three lines, trading more vertical space for horizontal space).

Comment: @LSpice. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I corrected a typo: $\Lambda^p(K)$ should be $\Lambda^p(K^n)$.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault . Thanks a lot, François !

Answer (score 16):

Here is a way to see that, for all $p$ (even if $p \nmid n$), you can reconstruct the absolute value of the matrix's determinant, which was suggested by Will Sawin's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416659/find-the-determinant-of-a-matrix-given-the-determinant-of-all-p-times-p-sub-ma/416677#comment1069136_416659). The condition $p \mid n$ is only needed to get the sign (or complex phase, if the ground field is $\mathbb{C}$).

If you know the determinants of all $p \times p$ submatrices of $A$, that means exactly that you know $C_p(A)$: the $p$-th [compound matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_matrix) of $A$. Since $\det(C_p(A)) = (\det(A))^\binom{n-1}{p-1}$, you can compute
$$
\lvert\det(A)\rvert = \lvert\det(C_p(A))\rvert^{1/\binom{n-1}{p-1}}.
$$

Comment: In fact, the eigenvalues of $C_p(A)$ consist of products of $p$ of the
eigenvalues of $A$. Let $M$ be the $n\times {n\choose p}$ incidence
matrix between elements of $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $p$-element
subsets of $[n]$. The Smith normal form of $M$ has diagonal entries
$p$ (once) and 1 ($n-1$ times), a special case of Theorem 3.6 of
https://people.clas.ufl.edu/sin/files/snf.pdf. This implies that the
$p$th powers of the eigenvalues of $A$ can be written as Laurent
monomials in the eigenvalues of $C_p(A)$.